# jSON jquery does not load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to fetch the data from my Mysql database without refreshing the page. I found the coding in technotip.com. The fetch.php file is fine and execute the data that i want and look the same like the one in technotip example. However, when I load the index.html file it does not load anything. Please help me.

Php file

```
<?php

    $fXg = 0;
    $fYg = 0;
    $fZg = 0;

    $alpha = 0.5;


    include '../connection.php';

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sensor1 WHERE id_wasp = 'Sensor1' and sensor='ACC'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    $result = array(); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
        $acc = explode(";",$info['value']);
        $X = $acc[0];
        $Y = $acc[1];
        $Z = $acc[2];

        //low pas filter
        $fXg = $X * $alpha + ($fXg * (1.0 - $alpha));
        $fYg = $Y * $alpha + ($fYg * (1.0 - $alpha));
        $fZg = $Z * $alpha + ($fZg * (1.0 - $alpha));

        //Roll & Pitch Equations
        $roll  = (atan2(-$fYg, $fZg)*180.0)/M_PI;
        $pitch = (atan2($fXg, sqrt($fYg*$fYg + $fZg*$fZg))*180.0)/M_PI;

        $frameno = $info['frame_number'];


        array_push($result, array('pitch' => $pitch,
                                  'roll'  => $roll));



        //echo "$pitch<br />\n";
        //echo "$roll<br />\n";
        //echo "$frameno<br />\n";
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));

    //print_r($result);

?>
```

my_script.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
done();
});

function done() {
  setTimeout( function() { 
  updates(); 
  done();
  }, 200);
}

function updates() {
 $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
   $("ul").empty();
   $.each(data.result, function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>Pitch: "+this['pitch']+"</li>
                    <li>Roll: "+this['roll']+"</li>

                        <br />");
   });
  });
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fetch/Extract Data From Database: jQuery + JSON + PHP+ AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the browser's console for any error

Comment: problem is in your jquery code by look did u check if your php code working fine where are you calling function updates here?

Comment: M.Chaudhry the Php file works just fine. what do you mean calling function updates? i just follow all the steps in the technotip.

Comment: it is in your document function updates() {
 $.getJSON ...... it is a function where you are calling that when ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recreated your issue locally and found the odd issue with it.  There was a syntax error with the following line:

```
$("ul").append("<li>Pitch: "+this['pitch']+"</li>
```

jQuery was not happy with the line breaks and if you bring everything into a single line, eliminating the tabs and line breaks, it works perfectly fine.

```
$("ul").append("<li>Pitch: "+this['pitch']+"</li><li>Roll: "+this['roll']+"</li><br />");
```

Comment: ok. i have tried your solution. however, the page index.html still execute nothing. is there anything wrong with my html file? there is nothing appeared in the page.

Comment: Provided your PHP page is producing results from the DB into the array for JSON to receive, the only other thing I can see potentially failing is the call to the jQuery plugin.  Have you tried linking to the Google library? I used this when testing your sample: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: thanks again princess. but it still not executing anything. :(

Comment: What is your PHP file outputting?  Is everything in the same folder? You can do a view source on this to see what's going on: http://jacklynwyatt.com/dev/stack/test.html And http://jacklynwyatt.com/dev/stack/jsontest.php should be how your PHP output looks provided your query is working properly.

Comment: wowwwwww! how did u do that?? btw, this is how my fetch.php execution looks like.   {"result":[{"pitch":3.0985066823711,"roll":-177.94777930302},{"pitch":2.6064383309232,"roll":-176.34599071273},{"pitch":5.6194650804578,"roll":-174.62810015991}]}

Comment: I used the basis of what you created.  I'm not sure what to tell you unless there's something else going on with one of your files causing a conflict.  I have added links to the test.html file I linked to above if you wanted to download the source for the HTML and PHP files to play with.  I will try to take another look for you later on :)

Comment: no no wait. look. this is your data.. {"result":[{"pitch":"1","roll":"1"}, ... compare to mine as above. look at my value. the " " is missing. what is that mean?

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  I actually thought the same thing and ran a quick test to make sure.  The PHP page is now outputting the first roll value as -1 and it still works.  Are you echoing or have any other space/etc on your PHP file?  If there is anything else other than the JSON being produced by that page, it won't work (though it doesn't appear that's the case if that's your full PHP file above and the connection.php is not outputting anything).

Comment: PrincessJakie. Thank you so much for your help. I have used your test.html and it ran successfully. Can you email me your full name so that i can include you in my thesis in the acknowledgement part. irfan_adzhar@hotmail.com thank you so much. You save my life!